# protorpc reading list from caller with FieldList

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-endpoints, protorpc

I have a webservice that is supposed to read a list from a caller, do some work, and then return a response.

```
  @endpoints.method(ARequestMessage, AResponseMessage,
                    name="call", path="call")
  def call(self, request):
    aList = request.in_list
    for stuff in aList:
       "do work here"
    return when I am done
```

Will the following `ARequestMessage` class work?

```
class ARequestMessage(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
  in_list = messages.FieldList(2, required=True)
```

I am not sure about my usage of `FieldList` in structure or in context. Please include a bit of code in response.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`FieldList` is not meant to be used, what you want is the `repeated=True` argument to your field:

```
class ARequestMessage(messages.Message):
  name = messages.StringField(1, required=True)
  in_list = messages.StringField(2, repeated=True)
```